# The "from" parameter of hook_mail() does not work in Drupal 8?

Tags: drupal-modules, drupal-8

I use hook_mail() to send html mails and everything works fine except the "from" parameter.

For the parameter "from" I would like to use an email that is different from the contact email of the site and so in the hook_mail I write:

```
$message['from'] = 'no-replyl@my-site.com';
```

But every time I send an email the "from" parameter is contact@my-site.com !

Comment: Can you post some code sample maybe we can spot the problem ?

Comment: Does your implementation of `hook_mail_alter()` use a pointer to `$message` ? Eg. `function mymodule_mail_alter(&$message) {` not the `&` before the variable.